# Excel formula into all cell array

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to fill in a formula in a lot of cells using a VBA. The workbook I'm working with looks like this:

[image: Data layout]

I'm trying to fill in a formula starting in B3. I first tried to define a range and insert formula, but my problem is that the range is never the same. Some data sets I have more columns and others i have more rows.

Is there a way to make a VBA that defines the range as all columns with content in Row1 and all rows with content in A?

The formula that I'm trying to inset is like this: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$N:$N;MATCH(Sheet3!$A:$A&Sheet3!B$1;Sheet1!$R:$R;0))`

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: You should look for the concepts of lastrow and last column. There are plenty of posts about that on this site that will give you an answer.

Comment: just as a hint: try Googleing `find lastrow VBA`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Siddharth Rout's  find mothod is very good.  It is better than usedrange method.

Comment: You might want to invest some time in understanding Tables (listobjects) and then write your code based on that. It simplifies matters a lot. Here's a nice introduction: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: @Dy.Lee do you have a link to Siddarth's method?

Comment: @Egalth. Yes,I have done a link to Siddarth's method. The method is  perfect.

Comment: @Dy.Lee I'm afraid I don't see any link..

Answer (score 0):

you could create a dynamic named range that can be used in VBA

Use the below to define the range

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1)-1)
```

Changing Sheet1 to that of your sheetname

Assuming that there areno blank columns or rowsin your data set etc.